# What happens when all 12 aliens are on board?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

Does the game end when all 12 aliens board the ship, or does it end when the ship needs 13 or more on board (or something else)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rulebook states the following on page 7 under "ways to lose the game":

"You'll also lose if you are asked to place a hostile alien on the board, and you don't have enough remaining to place. (See "Hostile Aliens" for details.)"

So if you run out of aliens to add to the board, then you're done for!

Have fun!

Tavis Parker
The Game Crafter